# Input attachments and multisampling

Tags: vulkan

I know how to use input attachments and multisampling separately. But I don't understand how these 2 features can be used together.

I have render pass with 2 subpasses and 4 attachments:

1. an image, which is presented;
2. a multisampled image with samples=N, which is rendered and resolved (into image #1) in the second subpass;
3. a multisampled depth image with samples=N, which is rendered in the both subpasses;
4. a multisampled image with samples=N, which is used as color attachment in the first subpass and input attachment in the second subpass.

If N equals to VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT, everything works fine. But if N equals to VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_4_BIT, I have a lot of errors:

- vkCreateRenderPass returns error code on Mi A1;
- vkCreateRenderPass returns success on Mi A2 lite, but I get a lot of warnings from validation layers:

  > Descriptor set 0x28107 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDraw() time: Descriptor in binding #0 at global descriptor index 0 requires bound image to have VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT but got VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_4_BIT.

Questions:

- Is it prohibited to use multisampled input attachments? I can't find anything about this in spec.
- I can resolve my image #4 in the first subpass into some other image (#5) which will be used as input attachment in the second subpass. Is it the only way to fix this problem?

Comment: What is "Mi A1" and "Mi A2"? Also, how do you change your shaders between the multisample and non-multisample versions?

Comment: @NicolBolas "Mi A1" and "Mi A2 lite" are Android phones. I don't change shaders. I change only rasterizationSamples in VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't change shaders.

Then that's your problem. The multisampling status of a texture is part of its GLSL *type*. You cannot fetch from a multisample input texture through a `subpassInput`; you have to use a `subpassInputMS`.

Comment: I don't have sampler. My input attachment is defined in fragment shader this way: layout(input_attachment_index = 0, set = 1, binding = 0) uniform subpassInput offscreenBuffer;

Comment: @FilippSlavnejshev: The principle is the same; I just used the wrong typenames. See the edited version.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it

Comment: But this doesn't fix warnings. How should I change my descriptor set layout? Vulkan validation layers don't understand that I want to use multisampled image. I use VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT type.

Comment: Ok, your answer is right. I had problems with ccache.

Comment: So what does it all mean and how to fix this problem?